# Infer Prop interface from styled-component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I try to infer my components' `Props` interface over exporting them whenever possible. This isn't an issue with class and functional components, but if I try to infer the `Props` interface of a `styled-component`, the prop is typed to `any` which is not ideal.

```
interface Props {
  bgColor: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Box = styled.div<Props>`
  background-color: ${(p) => p.bgColor};
`;

const Button = (props: Props) => (
  <button style={{ backgroundColor: props.bgColor }}>{props.children}</button>
);

type ButtonInferredProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof Button>;

type BoxInferredProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof Box>;

const OtherBox = (props: BoxInferredProps) => (
  <div style={{ backgroundColor: props.bgColor }}>{props.children}</div>
);

const OtherButton = (props: ButtonInferredProps) => (
  <button style={{ backgroundColor: props.bgColor }}>{props.children}</button>
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Box bgColor="red">Hi! I'm a box! </Box>
      <OtherBox bgColor="purple" backgroundColor="red">
        Hi! I'm another box
      </OtherBox>
      <Button bgColor="blue">Hi! I'm a button</Button>
      <OtherButton bgColor="green">Hi! I'm another button</OtherButton>
    </>
  );
}
```

With `Box` being a `styled-component`, I can't properly infer its Props interface. When I create another component that uses attempts to use the inferred Props type, it comes through as any:

```
const OtherBox = (props: BoxInferredProps) => (
  {/* TS won't complain that `props` doesn't have a `iAmNotTyped` property which is desired... */}
  <div style={{ backgroundColor: props.iAmNotTyped}}>{props.children}</div>
);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-typescript-forked-7cq4q?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: it seems this is an issue with the types of styled components: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/52112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a type like this:

```html
import {
 StyledComponentInnerComponent,
 StyledComponentInnerOtherProps,
 AnyStyledComponent
} from 'styled-components';

type inferStyledTypes<T extends AnyStyledComponent> = 
  React.ComponentProps<StyledComponentInnerComponent<T>>
  & StyledComponentInnerOtherProps<T>;

// Use the above type to infer the props:
type BoxInferredProps = inferStyledTypes<typeof Box>
```

Answer (score 6):

`styled-components` exports a Typescript helper for this.

It's called `StyledComponentPropsWithRef`:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled, { StyledComponentPropsWithRef } from 'styled-components';

const RedLink = styled.a`
  color: red;
`;

type Props = StyledComponentPropsWithRef<typeof RedLink>;

const Link = (props: Props) => <RedLink {...props} />;

export default function App() {
  return <Link href="/" role="button" />;
}
```

This code works ☝️

Comment: This doesn't appear to include "theme" prop

Comment: This does not include custom props being defined inline, for example: `styled.input<{error?: boolean}>""`

Answer (score 3):

The type for your Box styled component is showing up as `StyledComponent<"div", any, Props, never>`.  So you can make use of typescript's `infer` keyword to extract Props from that type definition.

```
import {StyledComponent} from "styled-components";

type StyledComponentProps<T> = T extends StyledComponent<any, any, infer P, any> ? P : never

type BoxInferredProps = StyledComponentProps<typeof Box>;
```

Now you get a typescript error, as expected, when trying to assign `backgroundColor` on OtherBox.

Comment: This is a fantastic try! Unfortunately, it does not return the type of the actual props of the react component that is styled. Also, styled-components exports much of this as `StyledComponentInnerOtherProps`. Pretty cool though!

Comment: @HassanNaqvi Can you describe the issue? The `BoxInferredProps` is resolving to `Props`, and intellisense and compiler errors are working as expected. Why is this answer not sufficient?

Comment: UPDATE - Ah ha! There are of course the props that are intrinsic to HTML elements - aria attributes, event handlers, etc... This answer does satisfy my original question elegantly, but @HassanNaqvi's answer is more robust.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried various examples in this thread and found that none of the proposed solutions work for all the use cases I have in mind.

I want to be able to infer props of these kinds of components:

1. Regular component
2. Styled component
3. Styled component with custom props
4. Vanilla components, like div, input, etc.

I was able to cover all the use cases with this type helper:

```
import { ComponentPropsWithoutRef, JSXElementConstructor } from "react"
import {
  AnyStyledComponent,
  StyledComponentInnerComponent,
  StyledComponentInnerOtherProps,
} from "styled-components"

export type InferComponentProps<T> =
  T extends AnyStyledComponent
    ? ComponentPropsWithoutRef<StyledComponentInnerComponent<T>> &
        StyledComponentInnerOtherProps<T>
    : T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | JSXElementConstructor<any>
    ? ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>
    : never
```

Now you get correct prop types for all of these use cases:

```
const StyledComponent = styled.input ``
const AdvancedStyledComponent = styled.input<{ customProp: boolean }> ``
const RegularComponent = (props: { customProp: boolean }) => null

InferComponentProps<typeof StyledComponent>
InferComponentProps<typeof AdvancedStyledComponent>
InferComponentProps<typeof RegularComponent>
InferComponentProps<"input">
```

Comment: This broke for me when I used .attrs, as the attributes I inserted there were required.  I had to rewrite:

``` typescript
export type InferComponentProps<T> =
  T extends AnyStyledComponent ?
    ( 
        ComponentPropsWithoutRef<StyledComponentInnerComponent<T>> &
        Omit<StyledComponentInnerOtherProps<T>, StyledComponentInnerAttrs<T>>
    )
    :
    T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | JSXElementConstructor<any> ?
      ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T> :
      never;
```